# Is there any standard institute which provides certification for drummers in India?

Tags: drums, exam

I have been practicing drums for over two years and I want to know whether we have any institutions which would conduct exams and provide certification for drummers in India ?

Comment: Googling 'Drum exams India' brings up Trinity College London, providing drum exams in India.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main drum examination services are Rockschool and Trinity Colledge. These both have international examinations availible. For more information see the following websites:
[Trinity Colledge Internationl](https://www.trinityrock.com/venues)
[Rockschool India](http://india.rockschool.co.uk/datesandfees)